# syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) using laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

i tried to retrieve user authenticator, but it gives me error `syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)`.

**UsersController.php**

```
public function index()
    {
        $users = User::where('id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
        @foreach($users as $user){
            dd($users->name);
        }
         return view('users.index', ['users' => $users]);
    }
```

I also try

```
public function index()
    {
        $users = User::where('id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
        @foreach($users as $user)
            dd($users->name);
        @endforeach
         return view('users.index', ['users' => $users]);
    }
```

Comment: dump `$users` to see it it's array or object

Comment: @pLe0mAx thx for answer i think is array coz when i try `$users = User::where('id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
            dd($users->name);`  its give me error `Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@foreach  @endforeach` used in blade syntax, try below syntax in controller

```
 public function index()
    {
        $users = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            dd($user->name);
        }
        return view('users.index', ['users' => $users]);
    }
```

But there is a misconception if you are querying with primary key you can easily find a user by `find()` method as below

```
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
$name= $user->name;
```

Comment: try to do this with find, you don't need a loop in that case

Comment: `$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);` work very well

Comment: `find()` method gives you a model instance, while `get()` method gives you the collection. You can use `findOrFail()` method instead of `find()`, it will throw a 404 error if the id does not exist on your table @Kawtar

Comment: you don't need to query again for the User ... `Auth::user()` returns the User ... `$user = Auth::user();` done